# Improving my method for solving iterative algebraic equations

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations

So I wish to solve the following $i$ equations for $\eta_i$

$$p(x)+\rho_i z_i + \frac{(u_id)^2}{2(\eta_{i-1}(x)-\eta_i(x))^2}+\rho_i \eta_i(x) = B_i$$ where we have the following definitions and $x$ varying between 0 and 1.

$p(x) = 1-x \\ B_i = p(0)+2z_i\rho_i + \frac{u_i^2}{2} \\ d = 0.1 \\ z = \{1,0.9,0.8,...,0.1,0 \} \\ \rho = \{0,0.1,0.2,...,0.9,1\} \\ u = \{1,1,1,..,...,1\} \\ \eta_1 = 1$

You will notice $z$ and $\rho$ are very rough approximations to linear lines and $d$ the discretisation is large. I have the following code to solve this system, which is already very slow. I feel I am not writing the most efficient code or making use of Mathematica properly. I wish to decrease the size of $d$ and have a much faster code. I think it is `Solve` which is slowing things down.

```
ρ = Table[0.1 n, {n, 0, 10}]
z = Table[1 - 0.1 n, {n, 0, 10}]
u = Table[1, {n, 0, 10}]
η = Table[y, {n, 0, 10}]
η[[1]] =  1
B = Table[1 + 2 z[[n]] ρ[[n]] + u[[n]]^2/2, {n, 1, 10}]

Do[η[[i]] = 
  Solve[1 - x + ρ[[i]]*z[[i]] + (d*u[[i]])^2/2(η[[i - 1]] - η[[
        i]])^2 + ρ[[i]]*η[[i]] == B[[i]], y], {i, 2, 10}]
```

Any pointers on how to use Mathematica properly to solve this system quickly?

**EDIT**

So I have modified the code so that it now solves quickly for each `η[[i]]`, however the problem is now plotting the results, because there is a nested `Root` in each `η[[i]]` there is an error regarding the equation not being well formed? Anyway the new fast code for calculating the `η[[i]]`

```
y /. Normal@
  Simplify@Solve[1 - x + ρ[[i]]*z[[i]] + (d*u[[i]])^2/(
       2 (η[[i - 1]] - y)^2) + ρ[[i]]*y == B[[i]], y, Reals][[1]]
```

Then drop the output from this into

```
Do[η[[i]] = 
   Root[d^2 u[[i]]^2 + 2 η[[-1 + i]]^2 - 2 x η[[-1 + i]]^2 - 2 B[[i]] η[[-1 + i]]^2 + 
      2 z[[i]] η[[-1 + i]]^2 ρ[[i]] + (-4 η[[-1 + i]] + 4 x η[[-1 + i]] + 
         4 B[[i]] η[[-1 + i]] - 4 z[[i]] η[[-1 + i]] ρ[[i]] + 
         2 η[[-1 + i]]^2 ρ[[i]]) #1 + (2 - 2 x - 2 B[[i]] + 2 z[[i]] ρ[[i]] - 
         4 η[[-1 + i]] ρ[[i]]) #1^2 + 2 ρ[[i]] #1^3 &, 1], {i, 2, 10}];
```

For some reason it doesn't run if you the `y/.Normal` line within the `Do` loop. Doesn't work for a `Table` either. Anyway, if you then try and plot this it runs forever, but just plotting the first 3 gives what looks to be the correct result, however it does come with a "not well formed polynomial" error.

```
Plot[{η[[1]], η[[2]], η[[3]]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't $x$ have an associated numerical value?

Comment: $x$ varies between 0 and 1

Comment: Your code contains `Eta[[i]]`, while `Eta[[2]]` is unknown.

Comment: @Feyre I don't understand what you mean. I'm just setting `\Eta[[i]]` to the solution iteratively

Comment: @Feyre It's solving for `\[Eta][[2]]` ... If you notice `\Eta[[2]] == y`

Comment: Oh, then the code you want is `Table[\[Eta][[i]] = 
   y /.
    
    Solve[1 - 
        x + \[Rho][[i]]*
         z[[i]] + (d*u[[i]])^2/
          2 (\[Eta][[i - 
               1]] - \[Eta][[i]])^2 + \[Rho][[i]]*\[Eta][[i]] == 
       B[[i]], y][[2]], {i, 2, 10}];`

Comment: @Feyre Sorry I made an error copying your code. Your code does not solve the system any faster than mine, which is the question at hand here.

Comment: @Feyre I have made an edit which now runs the calculation of each `Eta[[i]]` quickly, but plotting them gives a strange error I have never seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotting `η[[i]]` is so slow, because it involves numerically evaluating `Root` functions nested `i` deep.  However, the time can be reduced to almost nothing by using `ListLinePlot` instead of `Plot` and evaluating `η[[i]]` numerically within the final `Do` of the question.

```
a = Table[1, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 11}];
Do[a[[i, j]] = η[[i]] = (Root[d^2 u[[i]]^2 + 2 η[[-1 + i]]^2 - 2 x η[[-1 + i]]^2 - 
    2 B[[i]] η[[-1 + i]]^2 + 2 z[[i]] η[[-1 + i]]^2 ρ[[i]] + (-4 η[[-1 + i]] + 
    4 x η[[-1 + i]] + 4 B[[i]] η[[-1 + i]] - 4 z[[i]] η[[-1 + i]] ρ[[i]] + 
    2 η[[-1 + i]]^2 ρ[[i]]) #1 + (2 - 2 x - 2 B[[i]] + 2 z[[i]] ρ[[i]] - 
    4 η[[-1 + i]] ρ[[i]]) #1^2 + 2 ρ[[i]] #1^3 &, 1]) /. x -> .1 (j - 1), 
    {j, 1, 11},{i, 2, 10}]
ListLinePlot[a, DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This works excellently, thank you.

Comment: @ojlm  By the way, if you need a function that produces numbers quickly rather than a `Do` loop that produces a table of numbers, `Fold` should work well.